# List all revisions that are merge points

Tags: svn, merge, mergeinfo

I'm looking for a way to get all points at which merges exist from one branch to another. I can see these from eclipse graph tool (want to say subclipse 4.3.0 provides this feature). However, I have yet to figure out a terminal command that can generate a full revision list nor a list of merge locations.

So far I've tried a few commands, including (svn log -v -g), but have run into some issues. Such as wrong version or format of repo for command. I suspect this is due to the remote repo being v1.6.11 and my local svn being v1.12.0. As well that the repo is format 12 (which I think is v1.7).

Additional when I run 'svn log -v -g' I get the following error:
svn: E200007: Querying mergeinfo requires version 3 of the FSFS filesystem schema; filesystem '/opt/svn/REPOS2/NAME/db' uses only version 2

I'm also new to svn so if you could explain any commands you provide or include sources that I can read up on that would be cool. I'm also using an older generation of mac if that matters. Which I'm also new to using as I traditionally use windows as my daily workstation OS.

Answer (score 2):

1. You (or repo-admin) **must** to upgrade your repository to 1.7-compatible format in order to use mergeinfo (`svn log --use-merge-history --verbose` require it) with `svnadmin upgrade`, after updating server-side SVN to fresh version (obviously)
2. `svn log -g -v` is the right attempt to get needed data

Comment: Any way around this as I don't have access to the repo to upgrade. As well we are already moving to git so doubt I can talk the team that manages it into upgrading.